# Adicionar itens dentro de um array para posteriormente salvar

Tags: php, ajax, array, laravel, laravel-5.3

Olá,
Tenho a seguinte situação e gostaria de uma dica se possível como seria a lógica para implementação deste procedimento na minha aplicação PHP Laravel.

Estou criando um sistema de estoque, na parte de movimentação, tenho uma view Entrada onde seleciona na combo um produto e clico em adicionar, toda vez selecionando um produto e clicando no adicionar deve ficar em memoria para que depois eu possa clicar em salvar e nesse momento salvar na tabela de movimentações.

Devo fazer isso utilizando ajax ou existe alguma outra maneira?

Preciso de uma ajuda para poder implementar este procedimento.

Comment: Existe várias formas, pode ser por exemplo com `AngularJs` e depois mandar via `ajax`, tem bastante forma.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução interessante é utilizar JSON. Nesse exemplo você utilizaria um form e passaria os parametros para o PHP via AJAX. Sendo necessário apenas adicionar os campos dentro do form com o mesmo nome.
Esse seria o retorno: {"nome":["teste1","teste2","teste3","teste4"]}

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

```
<body>
    <form id='formulario'>
        <input name='nome' value='teste1'>
        <input name='nome' value='teste2'>
        <input name='nome' value='teste3'>
        <input name='nome' value='teste4'>
    </form>

    <script>
    $.fn.serializeObject = function()
    {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function() {
            if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };


    $('document').ready(function(){
        json = JSON.stringify($("#formulario").serializeObject());
        $('body').html(json);
    });
    </script>
</body>
```